# iOS Swift How to go back from a split view to a normall view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I have a simple iOS app that I want to use a split view in, but I also need some normal view controllers(non Split view). So I have my story board setup like this:
[Story board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt1tm.png)

I will add more views to the base navigation view depending on what they click on in the first view some will go to other standard views and one will go to another split view. as I can not add the split view to my base navigation view (get an error saying it had to be the root view) I replace the root view with the split when the button is clicked using a replace Segue.

**My question is:** how do I get back to the first view once I am in the splitview? can I somehow had a custom back button to the detail view title bar to go back? Or am I going about the whole thing wrong? Any help or a push in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem myself. Unfortunately, `UISplitViewController` cannot be added as a child of another view controller. I must be the root view controller of a window. From the docs: `When building your app’s user interface, the split view controller is typically the root view controller of your app’s window`. The way I got around this was just creating a container view controller in my storyboard: It ended up looking like this: [image]

It's pretty basic, just adding the two view controllers as children of the parent view controller. You can control the width of each on straight in IB.

Comment: So once I create the container view I can detect the device in use some how, then choose to hide one on phone or display both on tablet?

Comment: You could do that, or use size classes in IB. I recommend using size classes.